# Jpgraph and the width (Y-axe)

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm using jpgraph to representate to graphic some variables, this variables have long width (from 1 to 10.000.000) and with jpgraph is all okey but i have a probles with the Y-axe, it simply to view:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/f2c2a

The axe its not complete and i cant view the rest of the numbers only 000000...

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution for this in the meanwhile? Thank you